# flask template converting two list in to different columns in table view

Tags: python-2.7, flask, html-table, jinja2

I have been trying to populate these output in flask template table view.But when it renders it displays the last list value in table (overwriting first list ). Can anyone please help me on how to create a new column when second list comes in to the picture?

**Python code:**

```
for i in mac:
    #sqlite query
    usage_list = cur.fetchall()
```

output of `usage_list`:

```
[5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
[10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]
```

**HTML code**

```
{% for item in usagelist %}
  <tr>
     <td> {{item}} </td>     

  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Desired output:
ex:

```
col 1  col 2

10.0   0.0
10.0   5.0
10.0   5.0
10.0   5.0
10.0   0.0
10.0   5.0
```

Comment: Each loop iteration generates a row with a single column. Are you sure this is what you want? To create a table, you probably need two nested loops, one for rows and one for columns.

Comment: @FlorianWinter Winter you are correct.I have tried with two nested loops.I can split those values,but can you suggest me how to pass those list for column and row separately?

Comment: You are talking about two lists, but in your code, there is only one list, called `usage_list`. Also, under "output of usage_list", you show two lists. Do you mean there is another variable, say `list2`, which is another list and which should be used to populate the second column?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot (easily) build a loop construct in the template engine that fits your needs, you can always transform the data before passing it to the template engine.

For example, you can transform two lists into a list of lists in Python:

```
table_data = [[list1[i], list2[i]] for i in range(0, len(list1))]
```

(You can probably also use `itertools.izip` here...)

then use nested loops to render the transformed data in jinja:

```
{% for row in tabledata %}
<tr>
  {% for item in row %}
  <td> {{item}} </td>     
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks i will check with this and get back to you and sorry for the late reply